# Commuting but not anti-commuting operators

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, commutator, anticommutator

Two Hermitian operators $\hat{A}$ and $\hat{B}$ are such that they commute but don't anti-commute. In this case, even they commute their uncertainty product will not be zero, is it right?

Comment: (almost) any operator pair that commutes doesn't anticommute, so I'm not sure why you think that there is something special about operators that commute "but don't anti-commute."

Comment: Is it even possible to have a pair of operators that "commute but don't anti commute"?

Comment: @Bob of course, any operator commutes with itself but doesn't anticommute with itself. Same with the identity, it commutes with any operator but it anticommutes with none.

Comment: @Snpr_Physics, you should clarify your question, why do you think anticommutation should have any effect on uncertainty (I assume that by uncertainty product you mean the product of their standard deviations with respect to some state?)

Comment: @user2723984 Noncommuting operators mean absence of simultaneous eigen states. This fact has something to do with their nonvanishing uncertainty product or not? If yes then what is the case when they commute but don't anticommute? In other words, Noncommuting operators mean absence of simultaneous eigen states. Does non-anticommuting have any type of such significance?

Comment: No, if they commute they have simultaneous eihenstates regardless of their anticommutator.

Comment: To amplify the point of @Jahan Claes, the potentially nonvanishing term of the  [Robertson–Schrödinger inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncertainty_principle#Robertson–Schrödinger_uncertainty_relations) in fact vanishes by virtue of sharing eigenstates.

Comment: To echo @Bob Can you have any pair of operators that both  commute $AB=BA$ and anticommute $AB=-BA$ --- unless both $AB$ and $BA$ are both  zero?

Comment: Ah, I realize I phrased my question incorrectly. I meant to ask is there any possible scenario where one can have a pair of operators that commute and anti-commute (other then the trivial case where both operators are zero)?